# How can I format cells in Excel to render the HTML they contain?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

Given an Excel spreadsheet with cells that contain HTML (in other words, content with markup), how can I get Excel to *render* that HTML rather than simply showing the combined content/markup? In other words, if a cell contains `<p>Here is some text</p>` I want Excel to display the content as a browser would (e.g., that content with some space above/below), not as raw HTML with the tags intact. I'm on the Mac in case it matters.

Comment: For a single HTML markup, you could develop your own VB parser. But if you expect putting the source code of a web page and it to show rendered, I don't think this is possible; this is a Browser job.

Comment: The cells contain not whole webpages but instead posts from a social platform. So it's mostly text wrapped in `<p>` tags with other tags interspersed (`<a>`, etc).

Comment: Then I'd create a parsing VB script that converts a few basic markups in an equivalent in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

See the post
[HTML Text with tags to formatted text in an Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999713/html-text-with-tags-to-formatted-text-in-an-excel-cell),
where the solution uses VBA.

The poster asked to convert this HTML text:

```
<html><p>This is a test. Will this text be <b>bold</b> or <i>italic</i></p></html>
```

into this:

> This is a test. Will this text be **bold** or *italic*

Here is the accepted answer by Siddharth Rout which converts the HTML
into rich text:

> Yes it is possible. In fact let Internet Explorer do the dirty work
> for you.
>
> **MY ASSUMPTIONS**
>
> 1. I am assuming that the html text is in Cell A1 of Sheet1. You can also use a variable instead.
> 2. If you have a column full of html values, then simply put the below code in a loop
>
> **CODE**
>
> ```
> Sub Sample()
>     Dim Ie As Object
>
>     Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
>
>     With Ie
>         .Visible = False
>     
>         .Navigate "about:blank"
>     
>         .document.body.InnerHTML = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
>     
>         .document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"
>         ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
>     
>         .Quit
>     End With
> End Sub
> ```
>
> **SNAPSHOT**
>
> [image]

The other answers in the post might also be useful.